# jQuery Sprites with Spritely

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, spritely

After 2 solid days of being stuck on one problem, I finally found a MUCH simpler way of making an animation from several frames... it's called [Spritely](http://www.spritely.net/).

#### [What I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/reveries/9Dt7n/9/)

```
var play_frames = 23;

$('#door_hov').hover(
    function() {
        $('#door').sprite({
            fps: 24,
            no_of_frames: 23,
            play_frames: play_frames
        });
        play_frames = 22;
    },
    function() {
        $('#door').sprite({
            fps: 24,
            no_of_frames: 23,
            play_frames: 22,
            rewind: true
        });
    }
);​
```

- When you mouseover, it starts the animation.
- When you mouseout, it rewinds the animation.

#### The problem

If you mouseout before the animation finishes, or mouseover before the rewind finishes, it winds up going too far and being out of sync.

#### What I want to do

- On mouseout, rewind ONLY to frame 1 and stop there.
- On mouseover, play ONLY until the last frame and stop there.
- If I mouseout (during animation) at frame x, I want it to rewind from frame x to frame 1.
- If I mouseover (during rewind) at frame x, I want it to play from frame x to the last frame.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, then you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9Dt7n/13/). Note: You might be able to shorten the code much more with the help of `play_frames`.

```
var iFrames = 23,
    iFps = 24,
    bRewind = false,
    iStartFrame = -1,
    bAnimating = false,
    stopAndRewind = function(oAnim) {
        iStartFrame = ~iStartFrame ? -1 : iFrames - 2;
        bRewind = !bRewind;
        bAnimating = false;
        oAnim.spStop();
    };
$("#door").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
    var iCurFrame = iStartFrame;
    if ($._spritely.instances && $._spritely.instances[$(this).prop("id")])
    {
        if (bAnimating)
        {
            iCurFrame = $(this).spGet("current_frame");
            stopAndRewind($(this));
        }
        $(this).destroy();
    }
    bAnimating = true;
    $(this).sprite({
        fps: iFps,
        no_of_frames: iFrames,
        start_at_frame: iCurFrame,
        rewind: bRewind,
        on_frame: (function() {
            var o = {},
                i = 1;
            if (!bRewind)
            {
                i = iFrames - 2;
            }
            o[i] = stopAndRewind;
            return o;
        })()
    });
});​
```